# Multiple Partial Views need the same Model - Only one 'model' statement is allowed in a file

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my view I have this:

```
    @Html.Partial("_MyView.Subsection1", Model)

    @Html.Partial("_MyView.Subsection2", Model)
```

But I get an error - `Only one 'model' statement is allowed in a file.`

How can I go about supporting my `Model` in multiple partial views?

Comment: If the model is not the same as the one you use in the parent view. Just create another model.
`public class MainPageModel
  {
    public Model1 Model1{get; set;}
    public Model2 Model2{get; set;}
  }`

Comment: It is... I have one @model, trying to send it to two partials

Comment: Remove the model and test if it works :)
Like so:
`@Html.Partial("_MyView.Subsection1")

@Html.Partial("_MyView.Subsection2")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are placing two model statements in your file like following:

```
@model Model1
@model Model2
```

This is not allowed, but you can merge both models into a single Model with two properties as follow:

```
public class MergedModel
{
 public Model1 FirstModel {get;set;}
 public Model2 SecondModel {get;set;}
}
```

So this way you can pass them to corresponding partial views:

```
@model MergedModel

@Html.Partial("_MyView.Subsection1", Model.FirstModel)
@Html.Partial("_MyView.Subsection2", Model.SecondModel)
```

Comment: I'm not... one `@model`, just sending it to two partials.

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to use the same model in both partial views you can do this:

```
@Html.Partial("_MyView.Subsection1") 
@Html.Partial("_MyView.Subsection2")
```

The model will be automatically passed in.